# Removing non-triple rows en masse in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, unique, rows

I have an array A that has 1 million rows and 3 columns. In the last column there are unique integers that help identify data in the other two columns. I would only like to keep data that has three of the same unique integer occurrences, and delete all other rows that have other amounts of unique integer occurrences (i.e. for unique integers that are only appearing once, twice, or four times for example). Below is a function remove_loose_ends that I wrote to handle this. However, this function is being called many times and is the bottleneck of the entire program. Are there any possible enhancements that could remove the loop from this operation or decrease its runtime in other ways?

```
import numpy as np
import time


def remove_loose_ends(A):
    # get unique counts
    unique_id, unique_counter = np.unique(A[:, 2], return_counts=True)
    # initialize outgoing indice mask
    good_index = np.array([[True] * (A.shape[0])])
    # loop through all indices and flip them to false if they match the not triplet entries
    for i in range(0, len(unique_id)):
        if unique_counter[i] != 3:
            good_index = good_index ^ (A[:, 2] == unique_id[i])
    # return incoming array with mask applied
    return A[np.squeeze(good_index), :]

# example array A
A = np.random.rand(1000000,3)
# making last column "unique" integers
A[:,2] = (A[:,2] * 1e6).astype(np.int)

# timing function call
start = time.time()
B = remove_loose_ends(A)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: May I ask why this function is called many times? I am asking, because depending on how the array is constructed, it might be possible to perform this check during the construction.

Comment: This function is being called many times as it is being used to smoothen out data from a highly non-linear process. Unfortunately it is not possible to inject any code into the process itself, leaving this exclusively to post-processing

Comment: Alright. I actually have an answer ready, but I am doing some timing. Unfortunately, yours takes quite a while to run just once ;)

Comment: That's great to hear! Very excited to see your work!

Comment: Alright, I cancelled yours after 15 minutes. Mine only takes 0.15s to run. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the main problem is that you loop over all the values twice basically, making it roughly an `n²` operation.
What you could do instead, is create an array of booleans directly from the output of the `numpy.unique` function to do the indexing for you.

For example, something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import time


def remove_loose_ends(A):
    # get unique counts
    _, unique_inverse, unique_counter = np.unique(A[:, 2], return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    # Obtain boolean array of which integers occurred 3 times
    idx = unique_counter == 3

    # Obtain boolean array of which rows have integers that occurred 3 times
    row_idx = idx[unique_inverse]

    # return incoming array with mask applied
    return A[row_idx, :]

# example array A
A = np.random.rand(1000000,3)
# making last column "unique" integers
A[:,2] = (A[:,2] * 1e6).astype(np.int)

# timing function call
start = time.time()
B = remove_loose_ends(A)
print(time.time() - start)
```

I tried timing both versions.
The function you posted I stopped after 15 minutes, whereas the one I give takes around 0.15s on my PC.

Comment: Wow this is brilliantly simple! This only seems to work for the sorted integers, but that is not a problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mcbw Sorted integers? The values in the last column are still floats, as the entire array is float. This solution should work for any 2D array with 3 columns.